# Java: Sort files in a folder in reverse semantic order

Tags: java, sorting, filenames, file-handling, comparator

I have a set of pdf files that I'm supposed to sort in reverse semantic order. The files are:

- Release_Notes_CNV_22.3.pdf
- Release_Notes_CNV_22.9.pdf
- Release_Notes_CNV_22.12.pdf
- Release_Notes_CNV_23.5.pdf

I have the following code to sort them. Unfortunately, the 22.3 file appears after 22.9. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong. A little help would be appreciated :D

The order I'm getting is:

- Release_Notes_CNV_23.5.pdf
- Release_Notes_CNV_22.12.pdf
- **Release_Notes_CNV_22.3.pdf** // 22.3 appearing before 22.9
- **Release_Notes_CNV_22.9.pdf**

The correct order should be:

- Release_Notes_CNV_23.5.pdf
- Release_Notes_CNV_22.12.pdf
- **Release_Notes_CNV_22.9.pdf**
- **Release_Notes_CNV_22.3.pdf**

My Code:

```java
private String getReleaseNotesPdfFileAbsolutePath(long number) {
        
            File folder = new File(String.format("%s%s%s", appHome, File.separator, releaseNotesFilesHomeFolderName));
            File[] fileNames = folder.listFiles();
            int i=1;
            
            Arrays.sort(fileNames, new Comparator<File>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                    float n1 = extractNumber(o1.getName());
                    float n2 = extractNumber(o2.getName());
                    int val = (int)n2 - (int)n1;
                    System.out.println(n2 + " " + (int)n2 + " : " + n1 + " " + (int)n1 + " : " + val);
                    return val;
                }

                private float extractNumber(String name) {
                    float i = 0;
                    try {
                        int s = name.lastIndexOf('_')+1;
                        int e = name.lastIndexOf('.');
                        String number = name.substring(s, e);  
                        i = Float.parseFloat(number);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        i = 0; // if filename does not match the format
                               // then default to 0
                    }
                    return i;
                }
            });
            
            for(File file : fileNames){             
                if( i == number ) {
                    return String.format("%s%s%s%s%s", appHome, File.separator, releaseNotesFilesHomeFolderName, File.separator, file.getName());
                }
                i = i+1;
            }
         
        return String.format("%s%s%s%s%s", appHome, File.separator, releaseNotesFilesHomeFolderName, File.separator, Constants.RELEASE_NOTES_PDF);
    }
```

Tried the above code using comparator.

Comment: So you extract the 22.3 and 22.9 into floats n1 and n2 - but then you do `int val = (int)n2 - (int)n1;`, casting them to ints for the comparison, so discarding the numbers after the `.` point !  Leave them as floats for the comparison - or better, extract the 2 numbers individually (eg the 22 and the 3) for the comparison - after all, I’m guessing you will actually want 22.11 to register as a greater number than 22.5

Comment: There are various 3rd party libraries that deal with semantic versioning, including maven-artifact, gradle, and semver4j, just as examples. While you can roll your own, using one of these may save you from inoccuous mistakes such as the int comparison spotted by @racraman. Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparing-versions for further inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that you compare decimal numbers. In the scope of decimals `0.12 < 0.3`, because `0.3 = 0.30`. But you want to compare decimal part as an integers, where `12 > 3`. To achieve this you need to first compare integer parts, and then decimal parts.

You can represent this as custom class:

```
class MyDecimal {

  private final int integerPart;
  private final int decimalPart;

  //constructor and getters
}
```

If you are using java 14 or above, record is even better.

Simplified example:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File[] fileNames = new File[]{new File("Release_Notes_CNV_23.5.pdf"),
            new File("Release_Notes_CNV_22.12.pdf"),
            new File("Release_Notes_CNV_22.3.pdf"),
            new File("Release_Notes_CNV_22.9.pdf")};

    Arrays.sort(fileNames, new Comparator<>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        MyDecimal n1 = extractNumber(o1.getName());
        MyDecimal n2 = extractNumber(o2.getName());
        //integer part first in reverse order
        int result = Integer.compare(n2.getIntegerPart(), n1.getIntegerPart());
        if (result != 0) {
          return result;
        }
        //decimal part second, if integer parts were equal
        return Integer.compare(n2.getDecimalPart(), n1.getDecimalPart());
      }

      private MyDecimal extractNumber(String name) {
        try {
          int s = name.lastIndexOf('_') + 1;
          int e = name.lastIndexOf('.');
          String number = name.substring(s, e);
          String[] parts = number.split("\\.");
          return new MyDecimal(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return new MyDecimal(0, 0);
        }
      }
    });

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileNames));
  }
}
```

Prints - `[Release_Notes_CNV_23.5.pdf, Release_Notes_CNV_22.12.pdf, Release_Notes_CNV_22.9.pdf, Release_Notes_CNV_22.3.pdf]`.